# Finding whether or not a counterexample exists

Tags: logic

Does a counterexample exist for the following argument?

> If person A is not home, then person B is. But, if A is not home, then B isn’t. So, they are both home.

Translated to logical notation:

1) $\neg A \to B$

2) $\neg A \to \neg B$

3) $\therefore A \land B$

To my understanding, a counterexample is when the premises are true but the conclusion is false. I've equated them as such, but I'm stuck in proving whether or not there is a contradiction, since there are too many cases to deal with (e.g. $A \land B \equiv F$ has 3 cases). How would I find out whether there's a counterexample or not?

1) and 2) seem contradicting already, but they also have 3 cases each.

Comment: _A_ can be home and yet _B_ does not need to. The first two statemets effectively say that _A_ must be home, but they imply nothing about _B_.

Comment: Does that mean that 1) and 2) are actually one premise, joined by a conjunction? Also how does this affect the argument? The conclusion says that only one of the two correct cases are true (the TT case).

Comment: The conclusion is false, since there is a possibility for _A_ and _B_ where the premises are true yet the conclusion is false. The correct conclusion should be just _A_.

Comment: Ah ok. So a counterexample does exist then?

Comment: Yes. ${} {} {}$

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the typo in the title, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To my understanding, a counterexample is when the premises are true but the conclusion is false.

Correct; more correctly, a counterexample invalidates an argument by making *all* premises true while falsifying the conclusion.

Here the conclusion is false if either of $A$ or $B$ are false.

Both premises are implications, which are held to be false *only if* the antecedent is true while the consequent is false.

Since the consequent of both implications are contradictory, then both implications can only be true *at the same time* if their antecedent is false.   Hence if a counterexample is to be found, $A$ must be true.

The way to make the conclusion ($A\wedge B$) false when $A$ is true is to make $B$ false.   And lo and behold: when $A$ is true and $B$ false then both premises are true.   Thus we have found a counterexample.

Therefore the argument $\neg A\to B, \neg A\to\neg B\vdash A\wedge B$ is proven to be *invalid*, by way of counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

We can say, from (1) and (2), that:

$$\lnot A\to (B\land \lnot B)$$

As $B\land\lnot B=F$, we have:

$$\lnot A\to F$$